# Valid expressions for default function arguments

Tags: c++, c++-faq

What are all the possible types of valid expressions for a default argument in a function or member function?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: My question is purposely general. I want to know what types of expressions that I can use as a default argument. SO is not just about asking for help fixing a bug.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1dbzf09.aspx

Comment: ¤ One special expression you can't use is `void()`. Unfortunately Visual C++ 10.0 accepts it. Other than that there is no restriction on argument default expressions compared to expressions in general. (Except if you're thinking of non-copyable types or such, which is not a restriction on the expression kind but on the type). If you are interested in the syntactical categories, then consult the C++ BNF grammar. Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that is correct within context of assignment to a variable of function parameter's type.

**Edit**
The default arguments during compilation are evaluated in terms of type correctness etc, but they are not calculated and no assignment takes place until run-time. You can specify a constructor of a yet to be defined class as a default argument and it's fine, as long as class is defined at the point of function use... The actual calculation/assignment takes place during function call, not at the point of function declaration/definition.

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>

void foo( int a = std::rand())
{
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main( void )
{
 foo();

 return( 0 );
}
```

[Program output on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/oTOnP):

`1804289383`

Comment: This is false. You can assign things to variable that can only be determined at runtime, but you wouldn't be able to use them as default arguments. For example, you can do `int a = std::rand()`, but you can't do `void Class::foo(int a = std::rand())`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'm letting my false preconceptions get the better of me again.

Comment: @EmileCormier The default arguments during compilation are evaluated in terms of type correctness etc, but they are not calculated and no assignment takes place until run-time. You can specify a constructor of a yet to be defined class as a default argument and it's fine, as long as class is defined at the point of function use... The actual calculation/assignment takes place during function call, not at the point of function declaration/definition.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification, and again, sorry about my crazy antics. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is detailed in section 8.3.6 of the C++03 standard.  It basically amounts to any expression that doesn't depend on anything in local scope, so any expression which depends on local variables, parameters to a function, or on "this" are excluded.

Comment: This compliments AzzA's answer very well. I wish I could accept both answers.