# assigning class variable as default value to class method argument

Tags: python, class, variable-assignment

I would like to build a method inside a class with default values arguments taken from this class. In general I do filtering on some data. Inside my class I have a method where normally I pass vector of data. Sometimes I don't have the vector and I take simulated data. Every time I do not pass a particular vector I would like to take simulated data by default. I thought it should be an easy construction where inside my method definition I say `a=self.vector`. But for some reason I have an error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.  The simplified construction is:

```
class baseClass(object):  # This class takes an initial data or simulation
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

class extendedClass(baseClass): # This class does some filtering
    def __init__(self):
        baseClass.__init__(self)
        self.z = 5
    def doSomething(self, a=self.z):
        self.z = 3
        self.b = a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = extendedClass()
    print a.__dict__
    a.doSomething()
    print a.__dict__
```

An output I expected should be:

```
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 5}
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3, 'b': 5}
```

I tried default assignment as `def doSomething(self, a=z):` obviously it doesn't work ever. As far as I understand `self.z` is visible in this scope and should not be a problem to have it as a default value. Don't know why I have this error and how to do it. This is probably an easy question, but I try to figure it out or find the solution with no lack for sometime already. I found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286533/how-to-use-an-member-variable-as-a-default-argument-c) questions only for other languages.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong. `self` is itself a parameter to that function definition, so there's no way it can be in scope at that point. It's only in scope within the function itself.

The answer is simply to default the argument to `None`, and then check for that inside the method:

```
def doSomething(self, a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = self.z
    self.z = 3
    self.b = a
```

Comment: In case the argument cannot take on falsy values, you should just write `if a: a = self.z` or even `a = a or self.z`.

Comment: I think you mean `if not a: a = self.z`

Comment: Is this a standard pythonic pattern, i.e. having a class property with a default that is used as a fall-back from an optional method property? Or is it better to change the `extendedClass` __init__ constructor to include an optional `z=None` property, and if `None` set it to some default inside the method, and not having it as a method parameter? I can only think that having a hard-coded class property is useful if it really is a constant, and required by more than one method, otherwise why not just restrict `z` to the scope of the method, maybe with no class or object property at all?

Answer (score 13):

Default arguments get evaluated only once, when the definition is executed. Instead, do this:

```
def doSomething(self, a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = self.z
    self.z = 3
    self.b = a
```

See also http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions.

Answer (score 11):

Here's the disassembly of the code for a simple example module. A code object is a read-only container for bytecode, the constants and names it uses, and metadata about the number of local variables, required stack size, etc. Notice that all of the code objects are compiled as constants. These are created at compilation time. But the objects `class A` and `function test` are instantiated at execution time (e.g. when the module is imported).

To make the class, `BUILD_CLASS` takes the name `'A'`, the bases `tuple` `(object,)`, and a `dict` that contains the attributes of the class namespace. This is like manually instantiating a type by calling `type(name, bases, dict)`. To make the `dict`, a function is created from code object `A` and called. Finally, the class object is stored in the module namespace via `STORE_NAME`.

In code object `A`, `self.z` is loaded on the stack as the argument to `MAKE_FUNCTION`. The bytecode op `LOAD_NAME` will search for `self` in the current locals (i.e. the class namespace being defined), the module globals, and builtins. This will obviously fail if `self` isn't defined in the global or builtins scope; it clearly isn't defined in the local scope.

If it did succeed, however, the function would be created with `(self.z,)` as its `__defaults__` attribute, and then stored to the local name `test`.

```
>>> code = compile('''
... class A(object):
...   def test(self, a=self.z): pass
... ''', '<input>', 'exec')

>>> dis.dis(code)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('A')
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (object)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object A ...>)
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             18 BUILD_CLASS         
             19 STORE_NAME               1 (A)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(code.co_consts[1]) # code object A
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)

  3           6 LOAD_NAME                2 (self)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                3 (z)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object test ...>)
             15 MAKE_FUNCTION            1
             18 STORE_NAME               4 (test)
             21 LOAD_LOCALS         
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

**@uselpa:** Your pastebin example (rewritten for 2.x):

```
>>> code = compile('''
... default = 1
... class Cl(object):
...     def __init__(self, a=default):
...         print a
... Cl()
... default = 2
... Cl()
... ''', '<input>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(code)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (default)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Cl')
              9 LOAD_NAME                1 (object)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object Cl ...>)
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             24 BUILD_CLASS         
             25 STORE_NAME               2 (Cl)

  6          28 LOAD_NAME                2 (Cl)
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             34 POP_TOP             

  7          35 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             38 STORE_NAME               0 (default)

  8          41 LOAD_NAME                2 (Cl)
             44 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             47 POP_TOP             
             48 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             51 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, class object `Cl` (and function object `__init__`) is only instantiated and stored to the local name `'Cl'` once. The module executes sequentially at run time, so subsequently rebinding the name `default` will have no effect on the default value in `__init__`.

You could dynamically instantiate a new function using the previously compiled code and a new default value:

```
>>> default = 1
>>> class Cl(object):
...     def __init__(self, a=default):
...         print a
... 

>>> from types import FunctionType
>>> default = 2
>>> Cl.__init__ = FunctionType(
...   Cl.__init__.__code__, globals(), '__init__', (default,), None)
>>> c = Cl()
2
```

This reuses the already compiled code object from `__init__.__code__` to create a function with a new `__defaults__` tuple:

```
>>> Cl.__init__.__defaults__
(2,)
```

Comment: I'm stuck. If the class and method are created at instantiation time, then why are they obviously not in my example on http://pastebin.com/UJfMpnqW ?

Comment: @uselpa: I added your example to hopefully clarify the difference between "compile time" and "run time". A module can compile fine with no syntax errors, but still have runtime errors when imported (executed).

Comment: I think I'm getting it. Thanks you very much for your patience!

Answer (score 4):

This will insert `self.z` if `a` is `None`/`False`/`empty_value`:

```
def doSomething(self, a=None):
        self.z = 3
        self.b = (a or self.z)
```