# Assign default values to method in class from other class

Tags: python, class, oop

I have the following project structure:

```
main.py
utils
----hudi.py
project
----stage.py
```

The main file will create an instance of the class in `stage.py`, that will create an instance of the hudi utils class. What I want is to set some attributes of `Stage` class as default values of the `Hudi` class.

The code of `hudi.py` is

```
class Hudi:
    def __init__(self, spark):
        self.spark = spark

    def test_hudi(self):
        print(self.spark)
```

My `stage.py` code is:

```
from utils.hudi import Hudi

class Stage:
    def __init__(self):
          self.spark="spark"
    def a(self):
          hudi = Hudi(spark=self.spark)
          hudi.test_hudi()
```

Reading the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15189304/9621172 I have tried with the following code:

```
class Hudi:
    def __init__(self, spark=None):
        self.spark = spark or self.spark

    def test_hudi(self):
        print(self.spark)


from utils.hudi import Hudi

class Stage:
    def __init__(self):
          self.spark="spark"
    def a(self):
          hudi = Hudi()
          hudi.test_hudi()
```

This way I expected that `self.spark` will be "transfered" to `Hudi` class without having to explicitly pass it (let's say that I want `Hudi.spark = Stage.spark`), but I get the error `AttributeError: 'Hudi' object has no attribute 'spark'`. What I want is even possible?

Comment: you cannot do `self.spark = spark or self.spark`. if the parameter `spark` evaluates false you will be doing `self.spark = self.spark` but `self.spark` is not yet defined

Answer (score 0):

Will static variables be what you want?
[Static class variables and methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-and-methods-in-python)
stage.py

```
from utils.hudi import Hudi

class Stage:
    def __init__(self):
          self.spark="spark"

    def SetHudi(self, spark):
          Hudi.spark = self.spark
          testHudi()
```

```
def testHudi():
    print(Hudi.spark)

class Hudi:
    spark = ""
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```