# Django model method paramter with default value from related

Tags: python, django

I need a model method with parameter with default value:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parameter1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=6, default=0)

    def my_method(self, parameter = parameter1)
        return parameter
```

But it doesn't work

Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [assigning class variable as default value to class method argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189245/assigning-class-variable-as-default-value-to-class-method-argument)

Comment: The short version is that Python evaluates the value of a default variable once, when the method is defined, not when the method is executed. So having a default value from the class is not possible. The next best thing is to have it default to None and replace None with the value you want.

Comment: @NickODell great explanation! Now everything is perfectly clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read @Nick ODell's comment, he's much smarter than me

but just add a little if!

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    parameter1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=6, default=0)

    def my_method(self, parameter = None)
        if parameter != None:
            return parameter
        return self.parameter1

        # or if you don't plan on passing 0 (zero)
        return parameter if parameter else self.parameter1
```

Comment: I did it in my code, but I was hoping to make it simplier. But now I hope it helps other noobies ;D