# Segmentation Fault while searching a node in BST

Tags: c++, search, binary-search-tree

I have written a search function in Binary Search Tree. While the function works properly and does what it should when the key is present in the tree but gives a segmentation fault when it isn't. Also is it right to print "yes" or "no" or should this function return a pointer to node?

```
template<class T>
class Node{
public:
    T m_data;  
    Node<T>* m_left;
    Node<T>* m_right;

    Node(T data){
         m_data=data;
         m_left=nullptr;
         m_right=nullptr;
     }
};

template<class T>
class bst {
private:
    Node<T>* root;

public:
    bst() { root = nullptr; }
    ~bst() { deltree(root); }
    void addnode(Node<T>* node, T data) {
        
        if(this->root == nullptr) {
            Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
            this->root = new_node;
        } else if(data > node->m_data) {
            if(node->m_right != nullptr) {
                addnode(node->m_right, data);
            } else {
                Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                node->m_right = new_node;
            }
        } else if(data < node->m_data) {
            if(node->m_left != nullptr) {
                addnode(node->m_left, data);
            } else {
                Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                node->m_left = new_node;
            }
        }
    }
    void addnode(T data) { addnode(this->root, data); }

    void searchkey(T data) { searchkey(data, this->root); }

    void searchkey(T data, Node<T>* node) {
        if(this->root == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Empty :) ";
        }
        if(data == node->m_data) {
            std::cout << "Found";
        } else if(node->m_data > data) {
            searchkey(data, node->m_left);
        } else if(node->m_data < data) {
            searchkey(data, node->m_right);
        }

        else {
            std::cout << "NOt fOUND";
        }
    }

void deltree(Node<T>* node) {
        if(node) {
            deltree(node->m_left);
            deltree(node->m_right);
            delete node;
        }
};
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated: I really expected to see a destructor in the `bst` class.

Comment: Note that you have a serious problem in `void addnode(Node<T>* node, T data);` - You create new `Node`s recursively. You should only create it when you've found a slot for the data, otherwise you create a lot of `Node`s that you leak. You also need a destuctor. 
[example](https://godbolt.org/z/Pqs71s)

Comment: Okay, I will take care of this. Thanks for pointing out! @TedLyngmo

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have tried to fix both the problems.

Comment: Much better. That shouldn't leak. You can make `addnode` a lot simpler though (as I showed in the example), but this'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if the `node` is `null` and hence are trying to access members (`m_data`, `m_left`, `m_right`) on a potentially empty node. Adding just a check is what you need.

Use this:

```cpp
void searchkey(T data) {
  if (this->root == nullptr) {             // <-- check if root is null in this function not
    std::cout << "Empty :) " << std::endl; //     the other one to reduce number of comparisons
  } else {
    searchkey(data, this->root);
  }
}

void searchkey(T data, Node<T> *node) {
  if (node == nullptr) {                   // <-- check if node is null
    std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
  } else if (node->m_data > data) {
    searchkey(data, node->m_left);
  } else if (node->m_data < data) {
    searchkey(data, node->m_right);
  } else {
    std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

It is better to return a pointer to node from such a function. If you are just checking then at anytime you can do so by directly comparing the result with `nullptr`. Overall, its your choice how you wanna implement it, and whether or not you aim to get a pointer to node.

**UPDATE - 2 :**

Improvised code by [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo): (Fixed memory leaks in `addnode`, simplified code and added destructor)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class bst {
private:
    struct Node {
        T m_data;
        Node* m_left = nullptr;
        Node* m_right = nullptr;

        Node(T data) : m_data(data) {}
    };

    Node* root = nullptr;

    void addnode(Node*& node, T data) {
        if(node == nullptr) {
            node = new Node(data);
        } else if(data > node->m_data) {
            addnode(node->m_right, data);
        } else if(data < node->m_data) {
            addnode(node->m_left, data);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Already Exists\n";
        }
    }

    void searchkey(T data, Node* node) {
        if(node == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Not Found\n";
        } else if(data < node->m_data) {
            searchkey(data, node->m_left);
        } else if(node->m_data < data) {
            searchkey(data, node->m_right);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Found\n";
        }
    }

    void deltree(Node* node) {
        if(node) {
            deltree(node->m_left);
            deltree(node->m_right);
            delete node;
        }
    }

public:
    ~bst() { deltree(root); }

    void addnode(T data) { addnode(root, data); }
    void searchkey(T data) { searchkey(data, root); }
};

int main() {
    bst<int> b;
    b.addnode(10);
    b.addnode(12);
    b.addnode(11);
    b.searchkey(11);
}
```

Comment: Just a query! when the pointer reaches on the leaf node how does it know "node==nullptr"?                                                                                                                        
         12
       /    \
      10     14
      /  \       / \
     8  11  13 15    What if am trying to find a node with key 112? How does it know "Not Found".

Comment: @TedLyngmo My bad. Doesn't work. :/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286551/11613622

Comment: @Tushar It isn't `nullptr` on the leaf node. But when you're on leaf node then either `m_left` or `m_right` is going to be null, which you are passing to the function in the recursive call.