# why data members of class cannot be assigned in methods

Tags: c++, oop

I tried this and error was

> error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::n'

Why cant we assign data member in method?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int n,m;
    public:
        A()
        {
           n=5;
           m=8;
        }
        void fun(int a,int b=n)
        {
            while(b--)
            {
                cout<<"XYZ";
            }
        }
};
int main()
{
    A obj;
    obj.fun(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The reason why is because the C++ language standard prohibits it.

Comment: Regarding `temp == 0` -- you should not do this, ever.  Use `!temp`, or `temp == nullptr` or `temp == NULL`.

Comment: @Biffen it is data member in class which is defined(I have mentioned it above). I have just pasted a part of which.

Comment: @paddy is there any reason why it is prohibited? Ohk I will keep that in mind about temp.

Comment: @Biffen this is the complete code. I have created the instance also.
https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/DklDK4hJxT

Comment: @Biffen I am sorry if i created some confusion(I tried to keep it very up to the point)
Class A
{
    int n,m;
    public:
        A()
        {
           n=5;
           m=8;
        }
        fun(int a,int b=n)
        {
            while(b--)
            {
                cout<<"XYZ";
            }
        }
}
why it is throwing error " invalid use of non-static data member " when we call method fun with 1 parameter

Comment: @biffen ohk i will add all the errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a member variable as a default argument in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286533/how-to-use-a-member-variable-as-a-default-argument-in-c)

Comment: @biffen yes it is method overloading but i asked that why we can't assign data members? why it is prohibited is there some reason?

Comment: @Sachin -- `temp == 0` is not forbidden by the language definition, just by some peoples' notions of good style. Its meaning is well defined. `0` is a null pointer constant, and comparing a pointer variable to 0 is just testing whether the variable holds a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a function is supplied by the compiler, so at compile time. At compile time the compiler can't know the runtime value of your variable. This is why it doesn't work.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-c/